# Writing a C++ simplifying wrapper for a C++ class with complex hierarchy so that Cython can call it

Tags: c++, python-3.x, wrapper, cython

I am trying to design a Cython wrapper for the C++ Computational Topology library GUDHI (http://gudhi.gforge.inria.fr). The GUDHI classes take other classes for their arguments, and these classes pass other subclasses to their methods. So rather messy to push straight to Cython. I have a code sample below.

I posted a question to the cython google group and someone suggested that I write a simplifying wrapper in C++ to hide this complexity from Cython. The [text](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/AdL5UEEEJ7A) of the comment is below.

> An alternative, if things get complicated, is to write simplifying wrappers in C++ and call those. (This used to be necessary before Cython supported any C++, and can still be useful if esoteric C++ features are being used, even if it's just a simple as declaring a couple of typedefs. In the code below, where it defines (and undefines and redefines(!)) macros to cope with what would otherwise be very verbose code this might be your best bet.) You can also do casts [1] (dynamic or otherwise) to convert between types that Cython doesn't know are related.

Here is a code sample to give you a sense of the hierarchy involved.

```
typedef CGAL::Epick_d< CGAL::Dimension_tag<2> > Kernel;

--- needs to be passed into


Gudhi::alpha_complex::Alpha_complex<Kernel> alpha_complex_from_points(points, alpha_square_max_value);

Epick_d.h

--- Epick_d.h depends upon these libraries

#include <CGAL/NewKernel_d/Cartesian_base.h>
#include <CGAL/NewKernel_d/Cartesian_static_filters.h>
#include <CGAL/NewKernel_d/Cartesian_filter_K.h>
#include <CGAL/NewKernel_d/Wrapper/Cartesian_wrap.h>
#include <CGAL/NewKernel_d/Kernel_d_interface.h>
#include <CGAL/internal/Exact_type_selector.h>
#include <CGAL/Interval_nt.h>

--- Sample source code for Epick_d.h

namespace CGAL {
#define CGAL_BASE \
Cartesian_filter_K< Cartesian_base_d<double, Dim>, \
Cartesian_base_d<Interval_nt_advanced, Dim>, \
Cartesian_base_d<internal::Exact_field_selector<double>::Type, Dim> \
>
template<class Dim>
struct Epick_d_help1
: CGAL_BASE
{
CGAL_CONSTEXPR Epick_d_help1(){}
CGAL_CONSTEXPR Epick_d_help1(int d):CGAL_BASE(d){}
};
#undef CGAL_BASE
#define CGAL_BASE \
Cartesian_static_filters<Dim,Epick_d_help1<Dim>,Epick_d_help2<Dim> >
template<class Dim>
struct Epick_d_help2
: CGAL_BASE
{
CGAL_CONSTEXPR Epick_d_help2(){}
CGAL_CONSTEXPR Epick_d_help2(int d):CGAL_BASE(d){}
};
#undef CGAL_BASE
#define CGAL_BASE \
Kernel_d_interface< \
Cartesian_wrap< \
Epick_d_help2<Dim>, \
Epick_d<Dim> > >
template<class Dim>
struct Epick_d
: CGAL_BASE
{
CGAL_CONSTEXPR Epick_d(){}
CGAL_CONSTEXPR Epick_d(int d):CGAL_BASE(d){}
};
#undef CGAL_BASE
}
#endif
```

**I am not sure how to design a C++ wrapper that will be compatible with Cython, but will also hide the hierarchy from Cython.**

Here is my idea, but I was not sure if this is what is meant by a simplifying wrapper. So a GUDHI class takes an array of n-dimensional points, and then does some geometric calculations on them. So right now if I want to wrap a GUDHI class directly, for example `Simplex_tree(subclass)`, then I need to inform Cython of this. Instead, I could write a C++ class that would just take the array of points, calculate the results, and then return an array. So in some pseudo-code something like

```
Class(*array)

     constructor(*array)

       loop: 

            take values from *array and create CGAL::Point_d

            push new CGAL::Point_d to std::vector<CGAL::Point_d>

       include all of the hierarchical class operations here.

     method_1(std::vector)

       include all of the hierarchical operations here, but
       return the result as a simple array or struct.
```

Would I then be able to wrap this class in cython without having to pass all of the class hierarchy, because I am only passing an array pointer to the function?

Answer (score 0):

This is what has been done on last [GUDHI version 2.0.0](http://gudhi.gforge.inria.fr/release/Gudhi-Release-2.0.0/).
A wrapper class Alpha_complex_interface (no more templated) wraps an Alpha_complex> to work in every dimension.
The class Alpha_complex_interface is then cythonized (cf. alpha_complex.pyx)
Then the points are exchanged through std::vector>&.
If you have any questions on the way I did it, or if you need other interfaces,do not hesitate.